# PHP shuffle function

Tags: php

I have an array of filenames gathered from a folder as follows:

```
$g = glob('uploads/thumbs/*.jpg');
```

Now, basing on the user choice, the images will be displayed in chronological order with an `rsort($g)` or shuffled by `shuffle($g)`.

The problem is that the shuffle always returns the same order of the pictures! How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you post your full code ?

Comment: As inspired by konsolenfreddy, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: `shuffle` returns boolean, not array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is some kind of reference problem, try this:

```
$glob = glob('uploads/thumbs/*.jpg');
$files = clone $glob;
unset($glob);
shuffle($files);
var_dump($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `srand()` to seed the random number generator, as it is used for `shuffle()`

Comment: although this is a valid answer, it shouldn't be a problem as of php 4.2. from the manual `4.2.0 The random number generator is seeded automatically.`